# Creating a variable field in model Django

Tags: django, database, django-models

I want to ask the user how many questions they want to ask; based on their response, I want to populate a model with those many fields. The way I am currently thinking about doing that is as follows:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Interview(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    number_questions = models.IntegerField()
    question_one = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='question_one')
    question_two = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='question_two')
    question_three = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='question_three')
    question_four = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='question_four')
    question_five = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='question_five')

class Question(models.Model):
    question_description = models.TextField()
    prep_time = models.IntegerField()
    response_time = models.IntegerField()
```

I realize that this solution is inefficient because a) the user is limited to a preset number of questions and b) if the user specifies less than 5 questions, there are unnecessary question entries created. What is a better way to go about storing multiple questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the foreign key relation the other way round. That's how you model a [many-to-one relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/):

```
class Interview(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()

    @property
    def number_questions(self):
        return self.questions.count()

class Question(models.Model):
    interview = models.ForeignKey(Interview, related_name='questions')
    question_description = models.TextField()
    prep_time = models.IntegerField()
    response_time = models.IntegerField()
```

Now you can access an interview's question via:

```
interview.questions.all()
```

An `Interview` can now have any number of `Questions`.
Btw, the `related_name` of all the `ForeignKeys` in your original `Interview` model should have been `'interview'` to make any semantic sense.